# ShopifyAPI: Product find since_id strangeness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

there is something strange going on with the Shopify API, I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I'd like to get from Shopify a list of all the products so I use the following code:

```
def get_all_products_from_shopify
  limit = 250
  all_products = Array.new

  self.connect_to_store
  products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit})

  all_products = all_products.concat products
  puts products.length
  while products.length == limit do
    since_id = products.last.id
    products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit, :since_id => since_id})
    all_products = all_products.concat products
  end
  ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
  return all_products
end
```

The issue is that I have 251 products on Shopify but with this method I retrieve an array of products that has a size of 277 elements.
Why?

Also if I do:

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.count
> 251

products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit})
products.count
>250
since_id = products.last.id
ShopifyAPI::Product.count(since_id: since_id)
>26
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: Can you provide your store url and API key please? It'll help figure out what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you David and sorry for the delay.  Adding a :since_id to the first query solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default products are returned in ascending order by **title** in the product list API.  Instead of omitting the `:since_id` param for the first page of results, use `:since_id => 0`.